# cannot use ResponseErrorWriter literal (type ResponseErrorWriter) as type error in GO

Tags: go

In my `GO` project I am getting an error in `server.go` file as,

> ## mygo/testkit/pkg/http/server pkg\http\server\server.go:24: cannot use ResponseErrorWriter literal (type ResponseErrorWriter) as type
>
> tigertonic.ErrorWriter in assignment:
>           ResponseErrorWriter does not implement tigertonic.ErrorWriter (missing WriteError method)

Here is my `init()` function, which gives the error in `server.go`.

```
func init() {
    tt.ResponseErrorWriter = ResponseErrorWriter{}
    tt.SnakeCaseHTTPEquivErrors = false // Ignored in ResponseErrorWriter anyway.
}
```

And I am getting the error at this line,

```
tt.ResponseErrorWriter = ResponseErrorWriter{}
```

What will be the reason for this error? How to solve this? I am new to this GO framework.

Answer (score 1):

From the message, `ResponseErrorWriter` is not a `tigertonic.ErrorWriter`. Meaning you haven't created `type ResponseErrorWriter struct` which implements interface `tigertonic.ErrorWriter`, so what you are trying to do is to initialize a struct which does not match the expected interface.

The message is clear, you need to implement the `WriteError` method.

Comment: I have imported `go-tigertonic` by,

`import (
 tt "github.com/rcrowley/go-tigertonic"
)`

And then I initialize `ResponceErrorWriter` in `init()` like,

`tt.ResponseErrorWriter = ResponseErrorWriter{}`

Then where I have supposed to implement `WriteError` ?

Comment: Have you created an ErrorResponseWriter struct ?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue relies on the following line from original [source code](https://github.com/rcrowley/go-tigertonic/blob/4d66e86f21fd4f5a6e54ed510bc076b9d870be6f/error.go#L74) :

```
var ResponseErrorWriter ErrorWriter = defaultErrorWriter{}

type ErrorWriter interface {
    WriteError(r *http.Request, w http.ResponseWriter, err error)
    WriteJSONError(w http.ResponseWriter, err error)
    WritePlaintextError(w http.ResponseWriter, err error)
}
```

Analyzing the above code it's clear that `ResponseErrorWriter` is defined as `ErrorWriter` which means that it's type is a custom type which implements the methods declared inside the interface. This means that you have to implement the methods declared as interface.

An interface defines a set of methods (the method set), but these methods do not contain code: they are not implemented (they are abstract). Interfaces in Go are some kind of contracts between the structs and the methods they needs to implement.

---

If you really need to implement your `ErrorWriter` interface, you need to declare your custom struct, which implements the method defined in the original `ErrorWriter` interface. Then you need to invoke the methods declared. How do you want to handle the errors it all depends on you.

If you check the source you will see that it implemented in the following way:

```
func (d defaultErrorWriter) WriteError(r *http.Request, w http.ResponseWriter, err error) {
    if acceptJSON(r) {
        d.WriteJSONError(w, err)
    } else {
        d.WritePlaintextError(w, err)
    }
}
```

The only thing left behind is to define the local struct variable as:

```
type defaultErrorWriter struct{}
```

Comment: So where I have supposed to implement `ErrorWriter` ?

Comment: There is a default ErrorWriter. If you do not want to write them in a specific way, you can let the default and it is just fine. In order to understand how it writes the errors, you can see the source code of this default `ErrorWriter` here https://github.com/rcrowley/go-tigertonic/blob/master/error.go#L80

Comment: Why do you need to override the `ErrorWriter` from the original code? Do you have any real arguments for this? If not you can use the default `ErrorWriter` just fine.